# ffmpeg resize + concatenate

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've tried just about every solution that's listed on this site, but i keep throwing errors trying to batch resize and then concatenate multiple videos.

```
!ffmpeg -i tearcash1.mov -i whiteflower1.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v0]; \
[1:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v1]; \
[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

Current Code throws this error:

```
[Parsed_concat_2 @ 0x55556d635900] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1024x576, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (865x576, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_2 @ 0x55556d635900] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output resolution after scaling may not match since you're scaling proportionally, and they should.

So, pad them to the same resolution, and ensure they have the same SAR.

`scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:-1:-1,setsar=1`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Do you have any suggestions about how I could extend this to automate the concatenation of any number of input videos in a specific folder?